# How to "pull out" styled HTML tags from I18N properties files with Makara module for Express and Kraken.js?

Tags: html, node.js, express, internationalization, kraken.js

I'm using [Makara](https://github.com/krakenjs/makara), an I18N module for [Kraken.js](https://github.com/krakenjs) and [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/).

Let's assume that I have a sentence where I want to style a specific word that happens to be in a random position because of each language grammars, and I want to easily handle it in different languages using I18N properties files before rendering stage, e.g.:

- I want to eat an **apple**
- Ich möchte einen **Apfel** zu essen

My properties files are:

```
//en-GB.properties
sentence=I want to eat an <span style="font-weight: bold;">apple</span>

//de-DE.properties
sentence=Ich möchte einen <span style="font-weight: bold;">Apfel</span> zu essen
```

CSS style is inline only for a sake of simplicity and bold style is just an example.

However, properties files are meant to contain just plain words. How can I get the same result without forcing HTML tags within properties files?

Comment: It really depends where in your tool chain internationalisation occurs. But if your markup is complicated, maintaining styling in multiple languages could become complex. It *might* be better to use a microsyntax in your properties file, and translate that to markup downstream. But there's no right and wrong, it depends on your situation.

Comment: Really good question. In general, I try to avoid that as much as possible (I prefer that translators have slightly less power to break the site) but yours is a pretty good example where alternatives can be rather cumbersome.

Comment: I understand that my question was kind of generic and probably there is no right/wrong answer. 
I'm using [Makara](https://github.com/krakenjs/makara), an I18N module for [Kraken.js](https://github.com/krakenjs) and [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/). However, any reference to existing modules/frameworks in any language that are able to support this is more than welcome in the comments.

Comment: There is indeed no right/wrong answer: there are situations in which translators may want to or have to change formatting. Some Chinese characters look awful in bold face, and the Chinese translator may prefer to use underline for emphasis. When translating German to English the translator may want to omit bold tags because an uppercase initial is enough to emphasize a word (`Klicken Sie auf <b>Sichern</b>` could be translated correctly as `Click Save`). What should be avoided is putting structural tags like `<li>` or `<td>` into localizable strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could handle configuration parameters is using placeholders instead of tags, and replacing them in phase of building your code using a tool, for instance "Grunt": I found out this Grunt task called "grunt-placeholder". Here is the link to the resource.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-placeholder

The configuration is based on json objects instead of properties, where you can create custom attributes and use them for your confguration purpouse into your files, before compilation.

- app/ui/componentA/de.json

  `{
      "componentA": {
          "title": "Titel der Komponente A"
      }
  }`
- app/ui/componentA/en.json

  `{
      "componentA": {
          "title": "Title of component A"
      }
  }`
- app/ui/componentA/componentA.html

  `<markup id="componentA">
      <div class="componentA">
          <div data-i18n="componentA.title;[title]componentA.title"></div>
      </div>
  </markup>`
- app/ui/componentA/componentA.less

  `.componentA {
      background: grey;
      color: red;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

> " I want to highlight a specific word"

In this instance I would recommend a specific element `<mark>`

`<mark>` at [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark)

> The HTML Mark Element (`<mark>`) represents highlighted text, i.e., a run of text marked for reference purpose, due to its relevance in a particular context.

```html
<p>I want to eat an
  <mark>apple</mark> for my lunch</p>
```

Comment: Better suggestion than dippas's, but neither answer really addresses the question which is about how to internationalise text that includes markup.